# fread() returns number of read bytes + 1

Tags: c, file, io

I use fread to read into a char buffer.

```
char buffer[50];
int nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, 50, fp);
```

The file I read from contains exactly the word *Hello*, i.e. 5 bytes.
In the above example, `nbytes` equals 6. Why?

Additionally, reading from a zero-byte file (i.e. it's empty) returns 0.

Comment: Maybe it's adding a 0-termination?

Comment: Does the file contain a newline?

Comment: `fread()`  and  `fwrite()` return the number of items successfully read or written. It is incorrect to say that they return a number of bytes. Though in your case since element size is 1, it is the same. But still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that whatever wrote to the file you are reading either included a newline (if it's a text file) or a 0 byte after the string.  If you are on unix, run the following command:

```
od -c filename
```

Which will print the entire contents of the file including non-printables.

You can also run:

```
wc --bytes filename
```

Which will print the length of the file in bytes (along with the filename).

Comment: try also `xxd filename` for a little more information. Also, `--bytes` may not be available as a `wc` argument on all platforms, prefer `-c`

Comment: Indeed. It seems like *gedit* is adding a newline to the file but does not display it in the editor. Thanks!